# NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist AWS S3 Codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codebuild

```
[Container] 2020/09/03 09:27:34 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2020/09/03 09:27:36 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.

    status code: 404, request id: , host id: = for primary source
```

Source provider: Amazon S3
Bucket: <bucket_name>
S3 object key: <folder_name>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to append a `/` at the end of the folder name. Otherwise it gave invalid key error.
As a result the S3 object key or S3 folder [in my case it was S3 folder]
It became `<folder-name>/`

Note the `/`

Comment: are you using nginx? i was same error and handle it by adding main address to s3 server `proxy_pass      http://localhost:9000/media/;` . in my case media folder was main address